# Why does an object still work properly without the class

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python. After reading some chapters of *Python Tutorial Release 2.7.5*, I'm confused about Python scopes and namespaces. This question may be duplicated because I don't know what to search for.

I created a class and an instance. Then I deleted the class using `del`. But the instance still works properly. Why?

```
>>>class MyClass:    # define a class
...    def greet(self):
...        print 'hello'
...
>>>instan = MyClass()    # create an instantiation
>>>instan
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x00BBCDC8>
>>>instan.greet()
hello
>>>dir()
['instan', 'MyClass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>>
>>>
>>>del MyClass
>>>dir()
['instan', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>>instan
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x00BBCDC8>    # Myclass doesn't exist!
>>>instan.greet()
hello
```

I know little about OOP so this question may seem simple. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python is a [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) language. When you do `del MyClass`, you do not actually delete the 'class object' (classes are objects too), but you only remove the 'name' `MyClass` from the current namespace, which is some sort of reference to the class object. Any object stays alive as long as it is referenced by something. Since instances reference their own class, the class will stay alive as long as there is at least one instance alive.

One thing to be careful about is when you redefine a class (e.g. on the command line):

```
In [1]: class C(object):
   ...:     def hello(self):
   ...:         print 'I am an instance of the old class'
In [2]: c = C()
In [3]: c.hello()
I am an instance of the old class
In [4]: class C(object):  # define new class and point C to it
   ...:     def hello(self):
   ...:         print 'I am an instance of the new class'
In [5]: c.hello()  # the old object does not magically become a new one
I am an instance of the old class
In [6]: c = C()  # point c to new object, old class and object are now garbage
In [7]: c.hello()
I am an instance of the new class
```

Any existing instances of the old class will continue to have the old behavior, which sort of makes sense considering the things I mentioned. The relation between name-spaces and objects is a bit particular to python, but is not that hard once you get it. A good explanation is given [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm).

Comment: Are the two classes in different namespaces?

Comment: There is only one name-space, but two class objects. This is somewhat hard to understand for newcomers or people that have experience with other languages. In my example, I first define the old class, which gets references by the 'name' `C` in the current name-space. When I define the new class, a new class object gets defined and `C` is updated to reference the new class. The old class stays alive, but now without being references by any name. A class object does not know or care about the name that references it. The effbot has a [good explanation](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm).

Answer (score 3):

When you delete a variable using `del`, you delete the *variable name* and your own reference to the object in the variable, not the object itself.

The object you created still contains its own reference to the class. In general, as long as someone still holds a reference to any object (including a class definition) it won't be deleted by the garbage collector.

Comment: `del` works on variables as such. I've edited this to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't store values in variables, it assigns names to objects. The [locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function will return all the names in the current namespace (or more specifically, the current scope). Let's start up a new interpreter session and see what `locals()` will give us.

```
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

The only names currently in the namespace are built in names that Python puts there at start up. Here a quick one-liner to show us only the names we've assigned:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v, in locals().iteritems() if k[0] != '_'}
{}
```

That's better. Don't worry about how that one-liner works, let's move on and create a class.

```
>>> class C(object):
        greeting = "I'm the first class"
```

When we define a class, it's name in places in the current scope:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v, in locals().iteritems() if k[0] != '_'}
{'C': <class '__main__.C'>}
```

The  part is Python's way of saying that there's an object that's too big to print out, but it's the class object we defined. Let's look at the memory address that our class object is stored at. We can use the [id()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function to find out.

```
>>> id(C)
18968856
```

The number that `id()` returns is the memory location of the argument. If you run these commands yourself, you'll see a different number, but the number doesn't change during a single session.

```
>>> id(C)
18968856
```

Now let's create an instance.

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.greeting
"I'm the first class"
```

Now when we look at `locals()`, we can see both our class object, and our instance object.

```
>>> {k:v for k,v, in locals().iteritems() if k[0] != '_'}
{'C': <class '__main__.C'>, 'c': <__main__.C object at 0x011BDED0>}
```

Every instance object has a special member `__class__` that is a reference to the class object that the instance is an instance of.

```
>>> c.__class__
<class '__main__.C'>
```

If we call `id()` on that variable, we can see it's a reference to the class `C` we just defined:

```
>>> id(c.__class__)
18968856
>>> id(c.__class__) == id(C)
True
```

Now let's delete the name `C` from out local namespace:

```
>>> del C
>>> {k:v for k,v, in locals().iteritems() if k[0] != '_'}
{'c': <__main__.C object at 0x011BDED0>}
>>> C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    C
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

That's exactly what we expect. The name `C` is no longer assigned to anything. However, our instance still has a reference to the class object.

```
>>> c.__class__
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> id(c.__class__)
18968856
```

As you can see, the class still exists, you just can't refer to it through the name `C` in the local namespace.

Let's create a second class with the name `C`.

```
>>> class C(object):
    greeting = "I'm the second class"
>>> {k:v for k,v, in locals().iteritems() if k[0] != '_'}
{'C': <class '__main__.C'>, 'c': <__main__.C object at 0x011BDED0>}
```

If we create an instance of the second class, it behaves like you noticed:

```
>>> c2 = C()
>>> c2.greeting
"I'm the second class"
>>> c.greeting
"I'm the first class"
```

To see why, let's look at the `id` of this new class. We can see that the new class object is stored in a different location from our first one.

```
>>> id(C)
19011568
>>> id(C) == id(C.__class__)
False
```

This is why the instances can still work properly: both class object still exists separately, and each instance holds a reference to its object.